# A correct/common way to log async calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Let's say we have a some async call of IO operation and we want to log it. 
The simplest way looks like this:

```
async def f():
   logger.log('io was called')
   await call_some_io()
```

But we obviously could hit the situation when we run `log()` function which switched a context and logged something else and only after this executed `call_some_io()`.

Next approach looks more robust:

```
async def f():
   await call_some_io()
   logger.log('io was called')
```

We are waiting for call_some_io() and after it we are logging it. Looks like in this case we have consistent calls.

But there is a third way to use context manager:

```
async def f():
   with LoggingContext:
     await call_some_io()
```

And the `LoggingContext` here is some ContextManager where `__exit__` method has some logging calls.

So the question is: which approach for logging asynchronous calls is most common and robust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All approaches are robust. The context manager might not be as common, but robust nevertheless.

However, examples #1 and #2 have different semantics. The first log message should read `about to call io` and not `io was called`, because no call has been issued yet.

The `LoggingContext` example is rather convenient for developers but equals example #2 in terms of execution order.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, I log messages after an action has been executed unless the action takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Using logging in a coroutine which starts another coroutine is relatively robust because as you have noticed it is possible to hit context switch. And actually there are only two cases: before and after awaiting and several possible approaches: log in a coroutine, logging decorator and logging context manager. I believe it is not an exhaustive list.

**Logging inside a coroutine to log before io start**

```
async def coro():
   logger.log('Before io start')
   await call_some_io()
```

**A decorator which logs before io start**

```
def logger(f):
    def warp(*arguments, **kwarguments):
        logging.log("Before io start")
        f(*arguments. **kwarguments)
    return wrap

@logger
async def coro():
    # Async logic...
```

**A logging context manager to log before io start**

```
class Logger(object):
     def __enter__(self):
        logging.log("Before io start")

     # Empty __exit__ ...

with Logger():
     await coro()
```

A little bit more tricky example of decorator which logs after io call.

```
def logger(f):          
    async def wrapper():
        await f()       
        logging.log("After io start") 
    return wrapper
```

A wrapper of decorator must be coroutine too to log an async call after io start. And it is definitely not robust to log async call with async logger ;)

In-coro and context manager approaches are easy to turn into logging after call so I'll skip an examples.

All these examples are equally common because Python is pretty artistic and there is no programming patterns devotion like in Java. So all the approaches look like Pythonic way to me.

Comment: the decorator that logs before the function, you should await f, not call it